# Constructor not defined: [CheckPostalAddress].<Constructor>()

Tags: apex, controller, extension

I have created a extension class and when i try and deploy i get the error as described in the title.  I have searched in the internet, but cannot see a resolution, therefore, if anyone has any ideas, that would be great.
Thank you all in advance

The Class

```
public with sharing class CheckPostalAddress {


public Boolean addressStatus {get; set;}

private ApexPages.StandardSetController stdController;


// Extension Constructor
public CheckPostalAddress(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller){
    this.stdController = controller;
}

// Standard Constructor
public CheckPostalAddress(){}



/** This is a dummy class to mimic an external call to a address verification web service @RemoteAction **/
@RemoteAction
public static Boolean CallAddressChecker(){

    // A dummy delay for the call to the web service
    // Plus not good practice in reality as could break the governer limits
    Integer start = System.Now().millisecond();
    while(System.Now().millisecond()< start+1000){

    }

    return true;
}
}
```

The Page

```
<apex:page id="CustomerSearch" Controller="ContactSearchController" sidebar="false" extensions="CheckPostalAddress">

<apex:form>

    <apex:pageMessages id="errors" />

    <apex:pageBlock title="Search Customer" mode="edit">

        <table width="100%" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="200" valign="top">

                    <apex:pageBlock title="Parameters" mode="edit" id="criteria">

                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            function doSearch() {
                                searchServer(
                                        document.getElementById("firstName").value,
                                        document.getElementById("lastName").value,
                                        document.getElementById("zipCode").value,
                                        document.getElementById("state").value,
                                        document.getElementById("ssn").value,
                                        document.getElementById("dob").value
                                );
                            }
                        </script>

                        <apex:actionFunction name="searchServer" action="{!runSearch}" rerender="results,debug,errors">
                            <apex:param name="firstName" value="" />
                            <apex:param name="lastName" value="" />
                            <apex:param name="zipCode" value="" />
                            <apex:param name="state" value="" />
                            <apex:param name="ssn" value=""/>
                            <apex:param name="dob" value=""/>
                        </apex:actionFunction>

                        <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-weight:bold;">First Name<br/>
                                    <input type="text" id="firstName" onkeyup="doSearch();"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-weight:bold;">Last Name<br/>
                                    <input type="text" id="lastName" onkeyup="doSearch();"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-weight:bold;">Zip Code<br/>
                                    <input type="text" id="zipCode" onkeyup="doSearch();"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-weight:bold;">State<br/>
                                    <input type="text" id="state" onkeyup="doSearch();"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-weight:bold;">Social Security Number<br/>
                                    <input type="text" id="ssn" onkeyup="doSearch();"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-weight:bold;">Date of Birth<br/>
                                    <input type="text" id="dob" onkeyup="doSearch();"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                    </apex:pageBlock>


                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        function ReverseDisplay(d) {
                            if(document.getElementById(d).style.display == "none") {
                                document.getElementById(d).style.display = "block";
                                document.getElementById('ShowHideLink').innerHTML = 'Hide Create Customer';
                            }
                            else {
                                document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none";
                                document.getElementById('ShowHideLink').innerHTML = 'Show Create Customer';

                            }
                        }
                    </script>

                    <a href="javascript:ReverseDisplay('uniquename')" id="ShowHideLink">Show Create Customer</a>

                    <div id="uniquename" style="display:none;">
                        <apex:pageBlock id="Create" title="Create Customer">

                            <script>

                                document.getElementById('CreateContactButton').style.display = "none";

                                function CheckAddress(){

                                    document.getElementById('CreateContactButton').style.display = "none";
                                    document.getElementById('CheckAddressStatus').innerHTML = 'Checking the entered address';

                                    var addressStatus;

                                    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                                            '{!$RemoteAction.CheckPostalAddress.CallAddressChecker}',
                                            function(result, event) {
                                                // Put the results into a var for pedantries sake
                                                addressStatus = result;

                                            });

                                    if (addressStatus){
                                        document.getElementById('CreateContactButton').style.display = "block";
                                        document.getElementById('CheckAddressStatus').innerHTML = 'Valid Address';
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        document.getElementById('CreateContactButton').style.display = "none";
                                        document.getElementById('CheckAddressStatus').innerHTML = 'Invalid Address, Try Again';
                                    }


                                }
                            </script>

                            <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-weight:bold;">Account<br/>
                                        <apex:selectList value="{!accounts}" multiselect="false" size="1" required="true">
                                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
                                        </apex:selectList>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-weight:bold;">First Name<br/>
                                        <input type="text" id="newFirstName" required="required"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-weight:bold;">Last Name<br/>
                                        <input type="text" id="newLastName" required="required"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-weight:bold;">Address 1<br/>
                                        <input type="text" id="newAddress1" required="required"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-weight:bold;">Address 2<br/>
                                        <input type="text" id="newAddress2" required="required"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-weight:bold;">Address 3<br/>
                                        <input type="text" id="newAddress3" required="required"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-weight:bold;">State<br/>
                                        <input type="text" id="newState" required="required"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-weight:bold;">Zip Code<br/>
                                        <input type="text" id="newZipCode" required="required"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-weight:bold;">Country<br/>
                                        <input type="text" id="newCountry" required="required" onblur="CheckAddress()"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-weight:bold;">Social Security Number<br/>
                                        <input type="text" id="newSSN" required="required"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-weight:bold;">Date of Birth<br/>
                                        <input type="text" id="newDOB" required="required"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                            <div id="CheckAddressStatus"></div>

                            <div id="CreateContactButton">
                                <apex:commandButton value="Insert Customer" id="CreateCustomer" action="{!runSearch}" rerender="results,debug,errors">
                                    <apex:param name="firstName" assignTo="{!firstName}" value="newFirstName"/>
                                    <apex:param name="lastName" assignTo="{!lastName}" value="newLastName"/>
                                    <apex:param name="accountID" assignTo="{!accountID}" value="newAccount"/>
                                    <apex:param name="address1" assignTo="{!address1}" value="newAddress1"/>
                                    <apex:param name="address2" assignTo="{!address2}" value="newAddress2"/>
                                    <apex:param name="state" assignTo="{!state}" value="newState"/>
                                    <apex:param name="zipCode" assignTo="{!zipCode}" value="newZipCode"/>
                                    <apex:param name="countryName" assignTo="{!countryName}" value="newCountry"/>
                                    <apex:param name="ssn" assignTo="{!ssn}" value="newSSN"/>
                                    <apex:param name="dob" assignTo="{!dob}" value="newDOB"/>
                                </apex:commandButton>
                            </div>
                        </apex:pageBlock>
                    </div>

                </td>
                <td valign="top">

                    <apex:pageBlock mode="edit" id="results">

                        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contacts}" var="contact">

                            <apex:column >
                                <apex:facet name="header">
                                    <apex:commandLink value="First Name" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="results,debug">
                                        <apex:param name="sortField" value="firstName" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                                    </apex:commandLink>
                                </apex:facet>
                                <apex:outputField value="{!contact.firstName}"/>
                            </apex:column>

                            <apex:column >
                                <apex:facet name="header">
                                    <apex:commandLink value="Last Name" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="results,debug">
                                        <apex:param name="sortField" value="lastName" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                                    </apex:commandLink>
                                </apex:facet>
                                <apex:outputField value="{!contact.lastName}"/>
                            </apex:column>

                            <apex:column >
                                <apex:facet name="header">
                                    <apex:commandLink value="Zip Code" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="results,debug">
                                        <apex:param name="sortField" value="zipCode" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                                    </apex:commandLink>
                                </apex:facet>
                                <apex:outputField value="{!contact.MailingPostalCode}"/>
                            </apex:column>

                            <apex:column >
                                <apex:facet name="header">
                                    <apex:commandLink value="State" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="results,debug">
                                        <apex:param name="sortField" value="state" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                                    </apex:commandLink>
                                </apex:facet>
                                <apex:outputField value="{!contact.MailingState}"/>
                            </apex:column>

                            <apex:column >
                                <apex:facet name="header">
                                    <apex:commandLink value="SSN" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="results,debug">
                                        <apex:param name="sortField" value="ssn" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                                    </apex:commandLink>
                                </apex:facet>
                                <apex:outputField value="{!contact.SSN__c}"/>
                            </apex:column>

                            <apex:column >
                                <apex:facet name="header">
                                    <apex:commandLink value="DOB" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="results,debug">
                                        <apex:param name="sortField" value="dob" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                                    </apex:commandLink>
                                </apex:facet>
                                <apex:outputField value="{!contact.Birthdate}"/>
                            </apex:column>

                        </apex:pageBlockTable>

                    </apex:pageBlock>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <apex:pageBlock title="Debug - SOQL" id="debug">
            <apex:outputText value="{!debugSoql}" />
        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I have a vague and possible false memory that when the controller extension is written for a custom controller it requires a matching constructor i.e. in your case public `public CheckPostalAddress(ContactSearchController scs) {}`. But looking at the error message I;m doubting that now..'

Comment: @KeithC You're right, actually. I'm mobile, so you want the rep for this one?

Comment: @KeithC - Good catch on the controller extending itself, although the error message posted does not seem to match the problem (not surprising). I would have expected to see `<constructor>(ContactSearchController)` or something similar....or I could just be reading it wrong.

Comment: @a-porter You mention that the compile error appears when you "try and deploy" the class. It that deployment between orgs, with something like a changeset. Or is that just deploying from an IDE to your development org?

Answer (score 1):

This class:

```
public class AbcController {
}
```

and this class:

```
public class AbcExtension {
}
```

when used like this:

```
<apex:page controller="AbcController" extensions="AbcExtension">
</apex:page>
```

generate this page compilation error:

> Error: Unknown constructor 'AbcExtension.AbcExtension(AbcController
>   controller)'

which can be fixed by this change:

```
public class AbcExtension {
    public AbcExtension(AbcController c) {
    }
}
```

So a similar change is needed to the code in the question though the reported error is for a different problem.